# Implement session timeout in cordova apps

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I want to implement session timeout in my cordova app but setTimeOut doesn't work properly. Is there a better way to logut user after x mins automatically if user is not using app for x mins even if app is in background

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the [session storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) for things like that. The session storage will be cleared, each time the app closes. You could encrypt the user login data or save sth. like a hash. On every App launch, check if the hash is available or not, if not -> prompt a login window.

Is that what you need?

Comment: My requirement is little different from what I mentioned as I wanted generic solution. Requirement is to auto login user if user is doing only client side activity. On other hand if user is not doing any activity app should get logged off automatically. Here I have to check background activity as well

Comment: What about using `pause` and `resume` event in your application with also a counter which triggers a function after time X. All that in combination with the session storage?